# list all functions defined in a file

Tags: python, vim

When editing a python file in vim;

What is a good way to get all functions or classes listed plus the opportunity to jump to the lines where they are defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little "manual" but:

```
:g/def\ .*
```

will show you the lines and, in normal mode, you can press `<line number>gg` to jump to that line.

Building on jan's self found answer below:

A user command GJ (for GrepJump!)

```
command! -nargs=1 GJ vimgrep <q-args> % | copen
```

Comment: You can also map a hotkey for that for convenience, like `:noremap <F1> :g/def/ .*`

Comment: Btw., if you replace % by \*\*/\*.py you get a list considering all .py files in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use ctags or some variant the default `:tag foo<Tab>` or `:tag <Tab>` command could be enough but you may get tags from other files:

[image: :tag foo<Tab>]

`:ilist def .*` is another solution. At the prompt, type `:<Number><CR>`:

[image: :ilist def .*]

But I love [CtrlP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736)'s `:CtrlPBufTag`:

[image: :CtrlPBufTag]

Answer (score 1):

TagList or Tagbar plugin. You will need to have ctags, or [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) installed.

Excerpt from my `.vimrc`:

```
Bundle "majutsushi/tagbar"
  nmap <script> <silent> <unique> <F4> :TagbarToggle<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it. If you use the `:vim` command, your search is redirected to the quickfixlist. Thus,

```
:vim /def\ ./ %
:copen
```

i.e. "do a vim[grep] in the current file" and "open the quickfix window"  to jump to the matches will do the task.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use method/class code folding with [jpythonfold](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2527):

[image: screenshot of vim editing session using jpythonfold]

Not exactly what you've asked for, but it does provide a nice display of classes, methods and functions that you can quickly navigate.